# Submtting data using $.ajax and retrieving values from $_POST array

Tags: php, ajax, forms, serialization

I'm having trouble retrieving my form Data that has been submitted via ajax like this:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log("fomData");
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin+ "/selfservicemanager/localtmfsetup/local_tmf_setup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success : function (){
            alert("success");
        }       
    });
});
```

I can see the data being sent over the network like this: 
[image]

But when I try to retrieve the data on the server side the $_POST array is empty.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
die();
?>


array (size=0)
  empty
```

Any ideas?  I've tried to stringify the data being sent, and also tried to decode the $_POST array but it expects a string.....

---

PART 2:

---

Yes I had tried the serialize function before and had started using the  serializeArray() function just to see if it might work. I've tried using jquery's $.post() instead of $.ajax() - but nothing seems to work.  However, I now think that this is a Chrome problem. I just tested on Firefox and it all works fine.  I've also looked at the response coming back in chrome debugger and interestingly enough, it is printing the $_POST array as XML like this:

```
 <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=7)</i>
  'weekly_out_of_office' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=3)</i>
      0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'monday'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'wednesday'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      2 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'friday'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
  'public_holiday_names' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  'public_holiday_value' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'6/17/2014'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
  'pay_day' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
  'final_approval' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'-1'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
  'final_output' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'-6'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
  'file_input_type_1' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'fdsff'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
</pre>
```

But when I try to access the values via PHP like

```
$final_approval = $_POST['final_approval'];
```

I get null

Not sure what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [**`$(this).serialize()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), also its not sending over the wire as you might think because your writing to console before its sent, so it just looks like it is.

Try this:

```
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin+ "/selfservicemanager/localtmfsetup/local_tmf_setup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success : function (resp){
            alert(resp);
        }       
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

With this you should get an alert back of the `var_dump($_POST);` by using `alert(resp);`

Or the latest way of doing it,

```
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function(event){

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin+ "/selfservicemanager/localtmfsetup/local_tmf_setup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    request.done(function( resp ) {
        alert(resp);
    });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Also note that there is no support for `window.location.origin` in IE so you will need to add something like the following when bootstrapping your JS

```
/* IE Fix for .origin  */
if(!window.location.origin) {
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port?':'+window.location.port:'');
}
```

### Update (Simple Example)

```
<?php 
/* check POST */
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    /* do std form handling ect */
    $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : null;

    //do the rest of logic ect
    //..

    /* Then finally respond with json if request from AJAX -
        this way you can handle javascript on and off browsers.
     */
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        //setup to respond with
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        //send back - example
        exit(json_encode(array('value_from_ajax' => $value)));
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input_form").submit(function(event){

        var request = $.ajax({
            //url: window.location.origin+ "/selfservicemanager/localtmfsetup/local_tmf_setup.php",
            url: window.location.origin+ "/ajax_test.php", // <--!
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        });
        request.done(function( resp ) {
            $("#ajax_resp").html(resp.value_from_ajax);
        });
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Example</h1>
<form method="post" action="" class="input_form">
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Da form</legend>

        <label>Value :</label>
        <input type="text" name="value" value="" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<p id="ajax_resp"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would also suggest downloading firebug if you use firefox. It can make your life a lot easier. Goodjob Loz

Comment: Thanks for the help - I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Cheers, yeah firebug or [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/firefox/)

Comment: Yes I have both Firebug & Web Developer.  The formData printout from above is actually from the Web Developer network tab (that's how I knew the data was being sent) Cheers for the heads up re: IE.

Comment: @LindaKeating regarding your edit, thats from your xdebug output (must be old because font tag was deprecated in the 80's ;p), its html not XML.. so it is sending back as expected, within php do `print_r($_POST['final_approval']);` your see it will return -1 in an alert

Comment: Ok I'm lost.  What does that mean?  -1? Are you saying that the $_POST does hold the values I want? How do I get them.... Am I close?

Comment: Its in the output -1, `final_approval' => string '-1' (length=2)`, check the update in a few seconds, ive answered the question but ill go ahead an post an example that you can build on.

Comment: Oh god - I get it now! doh! -1 IS the value.